# PHP check if a radio button is clicked

Tags: php, mysql

I want to know if the user clicks the submit button, it will check if the user checks all radiobuttons.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
  $stmt = $conn->prepare( "SELECT *
      FROM tblquiz ORDER BY rand()" );
      $stmt->execute();

  ?>
  <form method="post" action="checkquiz.php">
    <?php 
    $number = 0;
    for($i=0; $row = $stmt->fetch(); $i++){
            $number++;  
            $id = $row['_id'];
            $question = $row['question'];
            $answers = array($row['answer1'],$row['answer2'],$row['answer3'],$row['correctanswer']);
            shuffle($answers);
    ?>

     <h4> <?php echo $number . ".) " . $question; ?></h4>   
     <label><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $answers[0]; ?>" name="<?php echo $question; ?>"> <?php echo $answers[0]; ?></label>
     <label><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $answers[1]; ?>" name="<?php echo $question; ?>"> <?php echo $answers[1]; ?></label>
     <label><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $answers[2]; ?>" name="<?php echo $question; ?>"> <?php echo $answers[2]; ?></label>
     <label><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $answers[3]; ?>" name="<?php echo $question; ?>"> <?php echo $answers[3]; ?></label>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

**CheckQuiz.php**

```
<?php 


if( isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //echo 'You clicked submit!';

    if(  ){

    } else {

    }


} else {

    echo "You didn't click submit!";

}


?>
```

Im a newbie so I really need your help. I want check first if all radio buttons have been checked and then check if the user's answers. Can you give me sample implementations of this? Your help will truly be appreciated Thanks.

Comment: You want to check whether user checked an answer right?

Comment: @Nouphal.M Yes that's exactly what I want

Comment: This means you want to check if any of the question is unanswered then user cannot click submit?

Comment: @user2936213 the user can still click the submit button, but in the next page I have to notify them that they have unanswered questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have name all your radio buttons with the same name. Say its name is `question`. example below

```
<input type="radio" name="question" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="question" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="question" value="3">
<input type="radio" name="question" value="4">
```

Then you can access its value from server as

```
if(isset($_POST["question"])){   
   echo $_POST["question"]; 
}else{
  echo "No answers were selected";
}
```

edited as per needed by user

if you have multiple questions then you could use like below

```
Question 1:

<input type="radio" name="question[1]" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="question[1]" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="question[1]" value="3">
<input type="radio" name="question[1]" value="4">

Question 2:

<input type="radio" name="question[2]" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="question[2]" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="question[2]" value="3">
<input type="radio" name="question[2]" value="4">
```

Then you could iterate as below:

```
   $quest = $_POST['question'];
   foreach($quest as $key=>$val){
         echo "Question ".$key." answer is ".$val."<br/>";
   }
```

Comment: I tried doing this, but it's only getting the last value of the 10 radio buttons,.

Comment: Try: name="question[]"

Comment: Yes I changed to question[] like this: <label><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $answers[0]; ?>" name="question[]"> <?php echo $answers[0]; ?></label>
   <label><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $answers[1]; ?>" name="question[]"> <?php echo $answers[1]; ?></label>
   <label><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $answers[2]; ?>" name="question[]"> <?php echo $answers[2]; ?></label>
   <label><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $answers[3]; ?>" name="question[]"> <?php echo $answers[3]; ?></label> but I can't select other answers

Comment: This last edit is Flawed. Naming all the boxes like `name="question[]"` will then force the system to have only one answer for each question, which is not desired. One question can have 4 possible options. This way it will tell php that there are 40 question with one option each.

Comment: I apologize for the mistake.

Comment: Again wrong. Add another set of `[]` after  `question[1]` and the rest

Comment: I don't mean any disrespect sir, but it works fine. Please try the code

Comment: @Nouphal.M what if I have too many questions? I don't need to code for  each questions and its answers

Comment: Yes it will work. if you give 2d index like `question[1][1]` etc then you would get some thing like `[question] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [4] => 4
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 1
                )

        )` So question[1],question[2]... is sufficient

Comment: Have added the iteration for you. Please check

Comment: @Nouphal.M there's some issue in the code, first I don't need to code for each question, i need some loop to do that, next in the code you provided I can select more than one answer in each question

Comment: @Nouphal.M thanks but I need to iterate in the quiz page not the checkquiz page?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45436/discussion-between-nouphal-m-and-dunkey)

Answer (score 2):

```
if(isset($_POST["radioBoxName"])){
   // It was checked
   echo $_POST["radioBoxName"]; // This is the value of the checked option
}
```

**Edit based on comments**

If you have lets say 10 questions with 4 different answers for each you can then name your radio boxes like this

```
<input type="radio" name="answer[1][1]"> Question 1 Answer 1
<input type="radio" name="answer[1][2]"> Question 1 Answer 2
<input type="radio" name="answer[1][3]"> Question 1 Answer 3
<input type="radio" name="answer[1][4]"> Question 1 Answer 4

<input type="radio" name="answer[2][1]"> Question 2 Answer 1
<input type="radio" name="answer[2][2]"> Question 2 Answer 2
<input type="radio" name="answer[2][3]"> Question 2 Answer 3
<input type="radio" name="answer[2][4]"> Question 2 Answer 4
```

Then you can check them in PHP like

```
// For 10 questions
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
{
     if(!isset($_POST["answer"][$i]))
     echo "You didn't answer Question number $i ";
}
```

Comment: What if I have 10 radio buttons?

Comment: Actually first I didn't understood how he will check all the radio boxes at first place as they are radios and not checkboxes, secondly, if is better to use a multi dimensional array, so that he doesn't have to write `isset()` for each checkbox group

Comment: 10 Radio buttons with one name? or different names?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky in every question I have 4 radiobuttons

Comment: @Dunkey please read what Hanky웃Panky is asking. Are your radio buttons of same name or different?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky 10 radio buttons with different names for each

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky hello tried this, but I can't select other answers in the question?

Comment: With a radio button you can only select one option and I guess that's what naturally is also correct. An MCQ can have only one answer. However if you want to select multiple answers for each question then you can use checkboxes.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky yes I know, but when I choose answers in another question, my previous answer gets disappeared?

Comment: Then you are probably mistakenly naming all of them like answers[1]. Make sure that every x in answer[x] corresponds to the question number

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45434/discussion-between-dunkey-and-hanky--panky)

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky but the example you provided, I have to code for each question, can you give me sample implementation to just use for loop ?

Comment: Please don't look to copy paste. I would rather like you learn the example and modify it to your needs. All you need to change in the example is to put `answers[$i][x]` rather than 1,2,3,4 and your existing loop will work with that.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky tried this<label><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $answers[0]; ?>" name="answer[<?php echo $i; ?>][0]"><?php echo $answers[0]; ?></label>
<label><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $answers[1]; ?>" name="answer[<?php echo $i; ?>][1]"> <?php echo $answers[1]; ?></label>
   <label><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $answers[2]; ?>" name="answer[<?php echo $i; ?>][2]"> <?php echo $answers[2]; ?></label>
<label><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $answers[3]; ?>" name="answer[<?php echo $i; ?>][3]"> <?php echo $answers[3]; ?></label>
But I can select more than one answers?